# Im struggling to get first print as "a is called" and then "b is finished"?

Tags: javascript

```js
async function b(a) {
  await a();
  console.log('b finished');
}

function a() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('a called')
  }, 1000)
}

async function exe() {
  await b(a);
}

exe();
```

// how to implement, provided 'a called' should displayed first and then 'b finished'?

Comment: Where are the promises? None of your functions explicitly returns a promise.

Comment: @jarmod I have to get the desired output using the promises?

Comment: make `a()` to return a promise that is resolved when the timeout is executed.